# Swift 5 storing and passing KeyPaths

Tags: swift, generics, swift5

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class User: NSObject {
  var name = "Fred"
  var age = 24
  var email = "fred@freddy.com"
  var married = false
}
```

I want to be able to write a generic function that takes in a list of `KeyPath`s for a known class type, read the values and print to screen. The problem is, the I can't get the following code to compile as the type of the `KeyPath`'s `Value` is not known, and will be different for each time. What do I have to do to make this work generically?

Consider the following:

```
struct KeyPathProperties<T> {
  var name: String
  var relatedKeyPaths: [KeyPath<T, Any>]
}

extension KeyPath where Root == User {
  var properties: KeyPathProperties<Root> {
    switch self {
      case \Root.name:
        return KeyPathProperties(name: "name", relatedKeyPaths: [\Root.age, \Root.email])
      default:
        fatalError("Unknown key path")
    }
  }
}
```

This line fails to compile:

```
return KeyPathProperties(name: "name", relatedKeyPaths: [\Root.age, \Root.email])
```

with this error:

`Cannot convert value of type 'KeyPath<User, Int>' to expected element type 'KeyPath<User, Any>'`

This is what I wish to be able to do, for instance:

```
let myUser = User()

var keyPathProps = KeyPathProperties(name: "name", relatedKeyPaths: [\User.age, \User.email])

for keyPath in props.relatedKeyPaths {
  print("Value: \(myUser[keyPath: keyPath])")
}
```

The above won't compile of course. Essentially I want to store keyPaths in an array at runtime, so I can generically at some point in time get values out of the `User`. I need to know if I can re-write the above in some way where the compiler can safely and correctly determine the type of the keyPath's value at runtime.

This is a conceptual use case for a much more complex architectural issue I'm trying to solve with hopefully less code.

MORE INFORMATION:

At runtime I wish to keep track of the properties that get modified - these properties are held in a modifiedProps array in each object / instance. At some point at runtime, I wish to be able to enumerate over this array of KeyPaths and print their values like so:

```
for modifiedKeyPath in self.modifiedProps { 
  print ("\(self[keyPath: modifiedKeyPath])" 
}
```

In short - I need to be able to capture the generic type of the KeyPath within `KeyPathProperties`. How do I achieve this?

SIDE NOTE: I can already easily achieve this by using Swift 3 style string based KeyPaths (by adding `@objc` to the class properties). I can store an array of keyPaths as strings and later do:

```
let someKeyPath = #keyPath(User.email)
...

myUser.value(forKeyPath: someKeyPath)
```

I just cannot do this with Swift 4 KeyPaths generically.

Comment: When you say "read the values and write it to a file," how do you plan to write that code? Start with that piece, and it will work backwards to the data structures you need. You can't write `Any` to a file (what if you were passed a UIViewController, what would you write? CBPeripheral?) so `KeyPath<T, Any>` certainly isn't what you mean. Deeply, how is your intended system different than `Encodable`? (And why not just use `Encodable` and write that to a file?)

Comment: That's actually not relevant to problem - I eventually plan to write JSON to disk, but essentially I need to be able to generically extract values out of instances of objects that I know the type of, but am trying to reduce the amount of code I need to write and don't wish to use `Mirror`

Comment: What you've written here isn't possible (using Any), so it still gets back to what you mean. If you mean "write JSON" then you mean "Encodable" right? And it sounds like you really mean "I want a list of Encodable keypaths that I will turn into a JSON string." Is that really what you're trying to build? (That's very different from "random keypaths I want the values from." Encodable keypaths return you Data, not randomly typed values.)

Comment: So I've updated the question - let's assume I only wish to print the values to screen. I realize `Any` won't work, that's why I posted the question. How can I generically store KeyPath's where the value type is not known and later be able to do loop over the "relatedKeyPaths" array and do something like this: myObject[keyPath: keyPath]

Comment: "Print the values to the screen" means "turn into a string." So you need strings, not arbitrary types, right? How you plan to use the data drives everything. It's not something you worry about at the end. What do you expect the static and unchanging return type of `myObject[keyPath: keyPath]` to be? And what do you expect the output to be if I pass you a `CBPeripheral`? The `description` value maybe? (CustomStringConvertible)

Comment: You cannot unite two key paths that represent properties that have different types into a single array, because the key paths themselves have different types too. So you cannot readily loop over "all key paths". It sounds more like you are looking for Mirror (even though you have oddly ruled it out).

Comment: I've updated the question again :D More details - I'm not worried about encoding / saving / turning KeyPaths into string. I want to store a KeyPath to later use it to read values out of an instance of an object.

Comment: myObject[keyPath: keyPath] would presumably know what the type of the returned value is if I can get the above to statically compile of course, which I have been unable to.

Comment: "I want to store a KeyPath to later use it" Well it's an object so just assign it to a variable. No mystery there.

Comment: You cannot - that's the problem. The variable needs to be declared statically with the type of the KeyPath that it will store. I need to store an arbitrary array of KeyPaths where each KeyPath has a different type (Bool, Float, String) etc. Thus the need for this to become generic in some way.

Comment: No, _you_ cannot — _that's_ the problem. What you need is not a "generic"; the problem is that this _is_ a generic. What you need is a _type eraser_. And you have one: AnyKeyPath or PartialKeyPath.

Comment: @matt of course, I wouldn't be asking a question if I knew how to solve the problem. `PartialKeyPath` is exactly what I needed! Thank you. That solves the problem.

Comment: @matt I see you edited the answer with the comment below, that answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you what your misconception is:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'KeyPath<User, Int>' 
    to expected element type 'KeyPath<User, Any>'
```

You seem to think that you can use a `KeyPath<User, Int>` where a `KeyPath<User, Any>` is expected, ostensibly on the grounds that an Int is an Any. But that's not true. These are generic types, and generic types are not covariant — that is, there is no substitution principle for generics based on their parameterized types. The two types are effectively unrelated.

If you need an array of key paths regardless of their parameterized types, you would need an array of PartialKeyPath or AnyKeyPath. It seems that in your use case the root object is the same throughout, so presumably you want PartialKeyPath.

Comment: Thanks - yes I'm aware of what the error means and I realize what I'm doing won't work. I'm trying to see if there's a way to do this in Swift.

Comment: Yes, but try as we might, we can't get you to say what "this" is.

Comment: "this" has been described in my question, which I've rephrased. I have two classes with their own set of properties, each subclassing `NSObject`. At runtime I wish to keep track of the properties that get modified - these properties are held in a  `modifiedProps` array in each object / instance. At some point at runtime, I wish to be able to enumerate over this array of KeyPaths and print their values: `for modifiedKeyPath in modifiedProps { print ("\(self[keyPath: modifiedKeyPath])" }`

Comment: But I've told you that an array of multivarious keypaths cannot be achieved by typing the array as a KeyPath parameterized on Any. What you need is an array typed as a type eraser.